# How to play multiple videos on a mesh?

Tags: animation, mesh

I found information on how to place a video or an animation onto a mesh. What I want to do is slightly different, however, and I'm guessing it relies on Keyframes, a system I know next to nothing about in terms of Blender. But, you know how the Star Wars movies always have the text flying away from the camera before the main menu, and there are scenes from the movie playing? I want to do something sort of like that, but on a six sided cube. I want different clips playing on each side, and I want the clips on each side to change every now and then. Thank you in advance!

Ethan

Comment: if you are just starting with blender take some time to explore the resources in this page: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: You can easily make an independent material with a different video texture applied to each face independently. It might be more difficult to have several different clips playing from inside the same material; it would probably be a good idea to combine every individual clip into a single sequence for each face. Ideally you would even combine all clips into a single atlas video texture combining all faces, and map each part to the corresponding face using UV mapping.